# Add Python module to Heroku PythonPath

Tags: python, heroku

I have a local python project on the python virtual environment ready to be pushed to Heroku. Once I do that, on Heroku I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VeRyPy'
```

I have even set a file .heroku-env to set the path from there but that is not working either. The thing is that this module is not installable from pip. Any ideas/recommendations?

VeRyPy link https://github.com/yorak/VeRyPy

Comment: "I have even set a file .heroku-env"—why would you do this? What makes you think a file called `.heroku-env` would do anything? Use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Don't mess around with your `PYTHONPATH`. Just... depend on the library.